# Google play still thinks I'm using "com.example" and won't let me upload

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I'm trying to publish my app on the play store. I tried to upload, and got the error that I need to "use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted."
So, I changed the package from com.example to com.MyPackage, and redid the "generate signed apk" thing (used the same key), and tried again to upload, got the exact same error as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `applicationId` on the `app/build.gradle`.

NOT the package name of the sources inside this directory `app/src/main/java/YOUR_SOURCES`